# LLVM Immutable Pass

Tags: optimization, llvm

I'm going through the LLVM Pass classes and didn't quite understand the [ImmutablePass](https://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#the-immutablepass-class). Can someone give an example of how is it helpful and when should we use it?

Comment: Suppose you're working on your compiler driver and there's a bug, and you want to add a few lines of code to print some log data. An ImmutablePass subclass is often a fine place to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the examples in LLVM itself: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/search?q=%22public+ImmutablePass%22. There are only 2 pages in the search.

By looking of the code itself, you can see that it is not doing so much lol: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/86341247c4a2ffa4328945b03e7a05b1c51c3889/llvm/include/llvm/Pass.h#L269.

As I see, if you consider not to use `runOnModule`, `runOnFunction` and affect LLVM module somehow, you can use `ImmutablePass`.

Soooooo, everything these passes additionally have:

- `initializePass()` which is settable by user
- `bool runOnModule(Module &) override { return false; }`

Personally, I remember that LLVM runs some immutable passes before meaningful passes, due if it won't be done, these other passes will segfault due the lack of some information...